# Error when using Jinja2 filter_value() in superset while filtering booleans

Tags: mysql, jinja2, apache-superset

I'm trying to create a filter that will be able to apply to multiple different charts based off of a column `pos_only`. Every time I've attempted it, superset returns with this [error shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EAYB.png). This is a [simple query example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0GvL.png), but this still happens in all the other ones.

I replaced the jinja parameter with just an `IN(TRUE,FALSE)` to make sure I'm not messing up the function and it works that way just fine. I'm new to using Jinja to filter queries, so I could easily be missing something. I've tried reformatting hoping a miracle occurs, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The [`where_in` filter](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/sql-templating/#available-macros) converts the list of values into a string suitable for an `IN` expression, so you don't have to embed it in extra brackets.

```
AND pos_only IN {{ filer_values('pos_only')|where_in }}
```

Comment: Thanks! That took away that first error but not now I get one that says "Error: COLUMN_NOT_FOUND: line 9:7: Column 'pos_only' cannot be resolved". that column very much exists and when I specify it with an 'ru.pos_only' to the left of the in, the error persists. I then specify it inside the filter_value() and the it will return to that original syntax error

Comment: Could you check the generated SQL after using the `ru.pos_only` field name?

Comment: Just wanted to add I know why the syntax error will occur when I add it within the filter_value(), but just wanted to try it to see what happened

Comment: `SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT ru.company_id) AS paying_company_count
FROM reporting.t_restaurantunit ru
WHERE 
    ru.pos_only IN {{filter_values('pos_only')|where_in}}
    AND ru.retired_date IS NULL
    AND unit_status = 'PAYING'`
This is what the new code becomes if that's what you're asking, but the error of pos_only cannot be resolved remains, although if I take away `filter_value()` out entirely and replace it with a basic `TRUE` or `FALSE`, it works

Comment: I mean with `filter_values('ru.pos_only')`. Could you obtain the final rendered SQL command?

Comment: No I cannot, but I did get it to work with the syntax I just sent. I think since the jinja filter runs based on the dashboard the filter is being pulled from, you can't run it while in the chart itself, even if its on the dashboard. But got it finally, thanks for your help!